# Why doesn't Folder.getFilesByName(name) find my file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

In a google drive folder, I have a document named "Tønseth and Øyen". It's not found by folder.getFilesByName("Tønseth and Øyen"). Every other file I have is found if I put their name in getFilesByName. Does it have something to do with the "Ø"? Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. `getFilesByName()` cannot find such characters of `ø` and `Ø`. But you can retrieve the files using Drive API. By using this method, filename included umlauts can be also retrieved. Please confirm the following script.

### Script 1 : Use DriveApp

I think that this is the most simple one.

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Tønseth and Øyen" and trashed=false');
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log("id=%s, name=%s", file.getId(), file.getName())
}

>>> id=#####, name=Tønseth and Øyen
```

If the file of "Tønseth and Øyen" is only one on Google Drive, you can use following simple script. This can be also replaced `folder.getFilesByName("Tønseth and Øyen")` of your question.

```
var file = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Tønseth and Øyen" and trashed=false').next();
```

---

### Script 2 : Use Advanced Google Services (Drive API v2)

**In order to use this script, please enable Drive API at [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) for Script 2 and Drive API at [API console](https://console.developers.google.com/) for Script 2 and Script 3.**

```
var params = {
  q: "title contains 'Tønseth and Øyen' and trashed=false",
  fields: "items(id, title)"
};
var res = Drive.Files.list(params);
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Result :

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "#####",
      "title": "Tønseth and Øyen"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

If you don't want to use Advanced Google Services (Drive API v2), you can also retrieve the files using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. In this case, you can use Drive API v3.

### Script 3 : Use `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. (Drive API v3)

```
var filename = "Tønseth and Øyen";
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(id,name)&q=name+contains+'" + filename + "' and trashed=false";
var params = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText();
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Result :

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "#####",
   "name": "Tønseth and Øyen"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why you have to use "title contains _" and not "title = _" ?

Comment: @Magnus You can see the information about it at here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171471/drive-api-v3-searching-on-list-service-doesnt-work-with-uppercase-accents/46171556?noredirect=1#comment79348911_46171556