# Drive API V3 - Searching on list service doesn't work with Uppercase accents

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I’m meeting a problem using the Google Drive API v3.

I have files in my Drive which have uppercase accents (screen 1).

When I use the Google API with the list method with this kind of q parameter :

name = ‘Évenement’

Nothing comes out. The problem seems to be the uppercase accent (it works fine in lowercase) in my word, the search works great with the Google Drive interface :

[image]

But it fails when I do it with the API :

[image]

How should I encode or modify my query to make it work ?

Please note that I’m trying to make this work in a Python application, and I meet the same problem (Also in AppScript), so this doesn’t seem to be related to the client used.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Drive API, files and folders with the name included the acute accent, umlauts and so on cannot be directly searched using `name=` for `Q`.

When it searches files and folders with the acute accent, please modify `Q` as follows, and try again.

#### From :

```
name='Évenement'
```

#### To :

```
name contains 'Évenement'
```

#### Result :

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "#####",
   "name": "Évenement'",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fit exactly my use case, but could be a workaround with a double check just after.

Is this limitation normal or is it a known bug ?

Comment: @switch I don't know whether that is one of bugs. But I think that the current workaround is this. I found this recently.

Comment: I will use that for now. I've also opened a ticket with the Google support. If they give me a better answer I'll write it there.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @switch Thank you for your support. Also I would like to search directly files with special characters.

Comment: Here the answer from Google :

"The drive UI search for the title isn't the same thing as using the query "name = '[filename]'". If you are looking for the same behavior as the drive web UI, they should do the query: 

fullText contains [filename] 

or, if you want prefix matching, you need to use "name" s.t... 

name contains [filename] 

Additionally, "name = [filename]" is case sensitive. If you use the operator "contains" instead of "=", then it's not case sensitive."

Comment: @switch Thank you for the additional information. I could understand the situation.