# Less-than sign in folder name in Google Drive API V2/V3

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a folder with name `b<bb` in my Google Drive root folder. When I try to list folders where title/name contains `b<bb`, the Google Drive API doesn't return it, however it works when I try `b<b`.

1. Trying to send a request with query `'root' in parents and name contains 'b<bb'`:
   https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27root%27%20in%20parents%20and%20name%20contains%20%27b%3Cbb%27

   The response is:

   ```
   {
    "kind": "drive#fileList",
    "incompleteSearch": false,
    "files": []
   }
   ```
2. Trying to send a request with query `'root' in parents and name contains 'b<b'`:
   https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27root%27%20in%20parents%20and%20name%20contains%20%27b%3Cb%27

   The response is:

   ```
   {
    "kind": "drive#fileList",
    "incompleteSearch": false,
    "files": [
     {
      "kind": "drive#file",
      "id": "0B8nHPp6YUJPJOU80TWFqSVpkNWM",
      "name": "b\u003cbb",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
     }
    ]
   }
   ```

The same issue is also when I use Google Drive API V2. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed that when Drive API v2 is used for your situation, I got the same result. But at Drive API v3, the file information can be retrieved using the query of `name="b<bb"`. On the other hand, it couldn't be done using `name contains "b<bb"`

About `=` and `contains`, there is a following comment from Google.

> The drive UI search for the title isn't the same thing as using the query "name = '[filename]'". If you are looking for the same behavior as the drive web UI, they should do the query: fullText contains [filename] or, if you want prefix matching, you need to use "name" s.t... name contains [filename] Additionally, "name = [filename]" is case sensitive. If you use the operator "contains" instead of "=", then it's not case sensitive.

The comment can be seen at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171471/drive-api-v3-searching-on-list-service-doesnt-work-with-uppercase-accents/46171556?noredirect=1#comment79348911_46171556).

The sample script using Drive API v3 is as follows.

### Sample script :

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=files(id,name)&q=name=' + encodeURIComponent('"b<bb"')
var params = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  muteHttpExceptions: true
}
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText();
Logger.log(res)
Logger.log(JSON.parse(res).files[0].name)
```

### Result :

#### `Logger.log(res)`

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "### file ID ###",
   "name": "b\u003cbb"
  }
 ]
}
```

#### `Logger.log(JSON.parse(res).files[0].name)`

```
b<bb
```

If this information is useful for you, I'm glad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however `=` doesn't work with `Ｂ<ＢＢ`, though `contains` works. Probably I should combine two options `=` and `contains` and use both to get list of files :(

Comment: @Alexander Shyronosov Yes. Also I think so. And the special characters are required to be used ``contains``. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171471/drive-api-v3-searching-on-list-service-doesnt-work-with-uppercase-accents/46171556#46171556).I think that a method that all characters can be used is important. So I would like to think of it under the current situation.