# DriveApp: searching for folders with non-Latin names

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I ran into what seems to be an issue inside **'getFoldersByName()'** method of the **Folder** class. If I pass a Cyrillic string as an argument, it returns the instance of **FolderIterator** as it should, but calling the **'next()'** method always throws an error ('iterator has reached the end').

The function below finds the subfolder with a given name inside the parent folder and returns the subfolder. If the subfolder already exists, the function returns it instead of creating a new one. Unfortunately, this only works with Latin subfolder names.

```
function findSubfolder(){

  var subfolderName = "Папка папка";  //string containing cyrillic characters

  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);

  var iterator = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(subfolderName);

  var folder = (iterator.hasNext()) ? iterator.next() : parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);

return folder;

}
```

It's worth mentioning that when I check *(existingSubfolder.getName() == subfolderName)* it returns 'true'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation. So please think of this as one of several answers. In my environment, I also had the situation like you. In my case, it occurs for `getFilesByName()`. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171471/drive-api-v3-searching-on-list-service-doesnt-work-with-uppercase-accents/46171556#46171556) I solved the situation by using `searchFiles()` instead of `getFilesByName()`. So I thought that this way might be able to be used for your situation. The modified script is as follows. It uses `searchFolders()` instead of `getFoldersByName()` as a workaround.

```
function findSubfolder(){
  var subfolderName = "Папка папка";  //string containing cyrillic characters
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  var iterator = parentFolder.searchFolders("title contains '" + subfolderName + "'"); // Modified
  var folder = (iterator.hasNext()) ? iterator.next() : parentFolder.createFolder(subfolderName);
  return folder;
}
```

If I misunderstand your question and this is not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Anton Dementiev I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.